# There is no Broadcast on android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have an android application which is registers with current sim card, running with my device.There is some user(current sim card) setting in the application.

Any other people with other sim card should not use my application setting and he has to registered with the application if new sim card is inserted(suppose in case I lost my device).
If I remove my sim card and inserted into other device and this application is also installed in the device, application should not ask for settings, because user(SIM card) is same.

I can capture the current simcard number by using  `TelephonyManager.getSimserialNumber()`. I also tried using `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED`, but working.
Please suggest me with sample example how to show notification when sim card is changed?

Is there any way to *broadcast* on *sim card change*?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @SRMTwo55am did you find the answer

Answer (score 1):

There is not any broadcast that determine about SIM change, But you can track the same by using "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" intent. when this intent get broadcast. there you can check for current sim number and previously saved number.

Answer (score 1):

The listening to "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" approach works for phones that do not have the "hot swap" enabled, in their case you can actually change the SIM card while the phone is on and just start using the new card normally.